# Get TemplateDoesNotExist Error when deploy django application to a pr0duction server

Tags: django, apache, deployment

Environment:

ubuntu on aws
django-1.4.5 in virtalenv
apache-2.2 with wsgi

django setting.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),)
```

apache2 error log:

```
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102] mod_wsgi (pid=1794): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/Sites/tushanwan/tushanwan/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102]   File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/django-1.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
[Mon Mar 11 22:18:55 2013] [error] [client 116.238.171.102] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

I have spent a day, and tried many ways to solve this problem on my aws ubuntu instance, but nor of them worked for me. I use the same way to deploy the django application on my local ubuntu server, and it works.

Comment: have you set your DEBUG = TRUE?

Answer (score 3):

from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

> If DEBUG is set to True (in your settings module), then your 500 view
>   will never be used, and the traceback will be displayed instead, with
>   some debug information.

so whereas in your development server everything may work fine, if in your production server you don't have a 500.html (in the root of your templates folder) then the framework will rise an error.

**A side note**: The 404.html and 500.html files are required in Django 1.4.x; in Django 1.5.x the 500.html and 404.html files are no more strictly required, thanks [to this patch](https://github.com/django/django/commit/8bd7b598b6de1be1e3f72f3a1ee62803b1c02010)

Comment: I added a 500.html to my templates. but still get a TemplateDoesNotExist error in my apache error log file with a render of the 500.html I added.

Comment: have you restarted apache? are the 500.html file permissions ok?

Comment: yes, the apache was restarted and the permission for 500.html is 644.

Comment: Is TEMPLATE_DIRS overwritten somewhere? What results from opening a django shell and typing "from django.conf import settings; print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS"?

Comment: As a workaround you can upgrade to Django 1.5. It should never rise this error. You can also temporarily set DEBUG and TEMPLATE_DEBUG to True to see if you get some hints. Finally we do not have any info on the cause of the exception... Maybe that as a conseguence of the exception some settings become unavailable?